# Mailto Attachment using javascript not working (Alternative way to achieve)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailto

`Mailto URI` does not allow to attach file due to security concern. Is there any other way to achieve this functionality?

When user clicks on **sendmail** button in my application, it is populating outlook desktop application (as I have used `mailto` URI), so I can only allow to use `mailto` option in my coding.

My application constructed by `HTML`,`JS`,`Node.js` (I should not use `nodemailer`)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There will be security concerns if it was. You can ask the user to upload the file to the server, retrieve the file and add the URL to the uploaded file in the message body in mailto:.